# requestAnimationFrame with multiple independent objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, requestanimationframe

I am attempting to animate two different objects, a div formatted to look like a square and another formatted to look like a circle.  I have a button for each object to start the animation which consists of just moving the object from left to right. I have included the code below.  The issue I am having is that if I click on the Move Square button and then click on the Move Circle button, the square moves back to the left.  What I am attempting to do is to move the objects independently of one another.

I am sure there is an object oriented solution for this but I have searched and have not found anything that makes sense to me.  Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var moveSquare = $('#moveSquare');
  var moveCircle = $('#moveCircle');

  var square = $('#square');
  var squareText = $('#squareText');

  square.css({
    top: '100px',
    left: '0px',
    color: 'white',
    position: 'fixed',
    'text-align': 'center'
  });
  var pos_square = square.position();
  squareText.html(pos_square.top + 'px' + '<br/>' + pos_square.left + 'px');

  var circle = $('#circle');
  var circleText = $('#circleText');

  circle.css({
    top: '300px',
    left: '0px',
    color: 'white',
    position: 'fixed',
    'text-align': 'center'
  });
  var pos_circle = circle.position();
  circleText.html(pos_circle.top + 'px' + '<br/>' + pos_circle.left + 'px');

  moveSquare.on('click', function() {
    console.log('movesuqare here');

    requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {
      starttime = timestamp;
      move(timestamp, square, squareText, 800, 5000);
    });

  });

  moveCircle.on('click', function() {
    console.log('movecircle here');

    requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {
      starttime = timestamp;
      move(timestamp, circle, circleText, 800, 1000);
    });

  });


  function move(timestamp, element, elementText, distance, duration) {
    var runtime = timestamp - starttime;
    var progress = runtime / duration;
    progress = Math.min(progress, 1);

    var leftPos = (distance * progress).toFixed(0) + 'px';
    element.css({
      left: leftPos,
      position: 'absolute'
    });
    element.css({
      'text-align': 'center'
    });

    var topPos = element.css('top') + '<br/>';
    elementText.html(topPos + leftPos);

    console.log(element.prop('id') + leftPos);
    if (runtime < duration) {
      requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {
        move(timestamp, element, elementText, distance, duration);
      });
    }
  }


});
```

```css
html {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.square_css {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.circle_css {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.shapeText {
  padding-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo URL; ?>views/index/css/index_Main.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <input type="button" id="moveSquare" value="Move Square" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="button" id="moveCircle" value="Move Circle" />
  </div>

  <div id="square" class="square_css">
    <div id="squareText" class="shapeText"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="circle" class="circle_css">
    <div id="circleText" class="shapeText"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>views/index/js/index_main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems is caused by the two animations sharing a common variable `starttime`.

To fix, you need some way of each animation having its own `starttime`.

There's a number of ways you could do that, the simplest of which is to pass a start time to `move()` along with the other parameters, from the click handlers. And because `move()` calls itself, `starttime` needs to be passed on to the next call.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var square = $('#square').css({
  'top': '100px',
  'left': '0px',
  'color': 'white',
  'position': 'fixed',
  'text-align': 'center'
 });
 var circle = $('#circle').css({
  'top': '300px',
  'left': '0px',
  'color': 'white',
  'position': 'fixed',
  'text-align': 'center'
 });

 var squareText = $('#squareText');
 var circleText = $('#circleText');

 var pos_square = square.position();
 var pos_circle = circle.position();

 squareText.html(pos_square.top + 'px' + '<br/>' + pos_square.left + 'px');
 circleText.html(pos_circle.top + 'px' + '<br/>' + pos_circle.left + 'px');

 $('#moveSquare').on('click', function() { // button
  console.log('movesuqare here');
  requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {
   move(timestamp, timestamp, square, squareText, 800, 5000);
  });
 });

 $('#moveCircle').on('click', function() { // button
  console.log('movecircle here');
  requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {
   move(timestamp, timestamp, circle, circleText, 800, 1000);
  });
 });

 function move(starttime, timestamp, element, elementText, distance, duration) {
  var runtime = timestamp - starttime;
  var progress = runtime / duration;
  progress = Math.min(progress, 1);
  var leftPos = (distance * progress).toFixed(0) + 'px';
  element.css({
   left: leftPos,
   position: 'absolute'
  });
  element.css({
   'text-align': 'center'
  });
  var topPos = element.css('top') + '<br/>';
  elementText.html(topPos + leftPos);
  console.log(element.prop('id') + leftPos);
  if (runtime < duration) {
   requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {
    move(starttime, timestamp, element, elementText, distance, duration);
   });
  }
 }
});
```

```css
html {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.square_css {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.circle_css {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.shapeText {
  padding-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo URL; ?>views/index/css/index_Main.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <input type="button" id="moveSquare" value="Move Square" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="button" id="moveCircle" value="Move Circle" />
  </div>

  <div id="square" class="square_css">
    <div id="squareText" class="shapeText"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="circle" class="circle_css">
    <div id="circleText" class="shapeText"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>views/index/js/index_main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Roamer-1888, Thank you very much for this, this is exactly what i was looking for.